# Adding a utility bar to a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, cti, utility-bar

does anyone know if it is possible to put the utility bar onto a lightning component.

More specifically the utility I need is the CTI dialer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you can, using [lightning:utilityBarAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:utilityBarAPI/documentation).

What you will need to do is to create a CTI dialer Utility using [lightning:clickToDial](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:clickToDial/example) and then include the utility in your lightning component.

However, this is only available in Lightning Experience. If you plan to use it say in Community or Standalone app, you won't be able to use it.

Here are few of the resources that you can refer to explore further on this:

- [Utility Bar API Implementation Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/utility_bar_impl_guide.pdf)
- [lightning:utilityBarAPI documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:utilityBarAPI/documentation)
- [lightning:clickToDial documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:clickToDial/example)